# How to clean survey data with SQL or Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, excel, vba

I'm currently trying to help our market research team prepare/clean some very messy survey data. I was given a  CSV file (plan to import into db table) with around 2000 people's responses to 30 questions.

The survey asked questions like "what is your favorite tv show?" or "what 3 mobile games do you play regularly?". Respondents were able to answer the questions however they wanted, so as you can imagine, the data is extremely messy.

So in the case of the mobile games question, responses often varied like this:

```
1. Candy Crush and Clash of Clans
2. Candy Crush Saga, Clash, Bejeweled Blitz
3. BEJEWELED
4. Pac-man
5. PACMAN
etc etc
```

What approach should i take  cleaning and unifying this data via SQL and or Excel? Obviously not trying to get everything, but as much as possible.

Comment: There's no way for a computer to tell that `Clash` is equal to `Clash of Clans` without a human developing the logic. Even then, how does the computer know that `Clash` isn't `Clash Royale` instead of `Clash of Clans`? Unfortunately, you aren't going to be able to automate this without error. If this is a one-off task, I would recommend just dumping to Excel and fix by hand. Writing an algorithm to fix this data is frankly, impossible. It would be difficult enough to find a way to split up your names by game successfully... you have no common delimiter so any `and` could be data... or not.

Comment: If you have columns indicating the question being asked, then you can start creating sheets or columns with responses per question.  In doing so, you would then try and use INSTR() or other functions to find similar/related responses per sheet/columns.  This will be a mostly manual process to find your heavy hitters, though can help collect the data after the fact with the functions.

Comment: You might be able to use `"Fuzzy Lookup"` to match up similar entries but it'd still take a lot of work https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011